# Windows 7 lookups on first host file entry

Tags: windows, hosts-file, lookup

Today my ISP blocked my internet due to suspicious activity - outgoing requests to malicious websites. Numerous scans of my machine couldn't reveal the culprit.
However, after doing a quick `netstat /f` I found the following:

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:5357         101com.com:49168       TIME_WAIT
TCP    192.168.1.21:49169     THOMSON:netbios-ssn    TIME_WAIT
TCP    192.168.1.21:49170     THOMSON:netbios-ssn    ESTABLISHED

TCP    127.0.0.1:49171        101com.com:49172       ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:49172        101com.com:49171       ESTABLISHED
```

Coincidentally, only a few days ago I decided to start adding servers to my host file. `101com.com` appears to be the first entry on my list.

So, am I actually sending out requests to `101com` even though it is being blacklisted? And if so, how can it be prevented?

Thanks.

Comment: No?  You are not sending traffic to that domain, you are sending traffic to 127.0.0.1, which is your local machine.  Your ISP wouldn't be able to detect that, since its your local machine, it never would reach any equipment they access.

Comment: [Its possible you have a rootkit](http://www.gmer.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's make something clear. `hosts` file doesn't prevent domain name resolution, it only overrides what domains resolve to.

When some program tries to resolve `101com.com`, your OS would normally query DNS servers for its IP address. But, if you have it in your hosts file, then `101com.com` will be resolved to provided IP without DNS query.

Domain name resolution still happens, but it's handled inside OS. All programs that try to resolve domains will receive IP addresses in response, but it will be the IP you have provided instead of DNS provided one.

`101com.com` is not "blacklisted", you have only redirected its traffic to your own machine (`127.0.0.1`).

Now, how can we explain `101com.com` in `netstat`'s output? That's pretty simple. `netstat` will try to reverse lookup domain names for IPs in the third column. You have defined `101com.com` as a domain name for `127.0.0.1`, so if you have a TCP connection from your machine (`127.0.0.1`) into your machine (`127.0.0.1`), then it can be as well shown as a connection from `101com.com` to `127.0.0.1`.

`101com.com` still exists for you, but now it points at your computer, not theirs. If your PC says something about `101com.com`, it means itself.

This has nothing to do with your ISP and he has no idea you have added some entries to the `hosts` file.

Comment: Thanks for detailed reply. Dont mean to go off topic, but should netstat reveal any suspicious activity (havent found any) or should i use third party network monitoring tools if i were to track origin of my ISP problem?

Comment: @Berins You can use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to monitor HTTP connections or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) to register all network traffic, but I'm not sure if it's worth it - maybe your ISP could tell you what suspicious behavior they have observed so that you know what to look for, or you could simply reinstall Windows (safest thing to do). Related question: [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/q/100360/194694)